# Scala Function Returning Object Type

Tags: scala

I have a definition that looks like this:

```
sealed trait ServiceResponse
  case object OK extends ServiceResponse
  case object SHIT extends ServiceResponse

  private def remoteService(waitTime: FiniteDuration): ServiceResponse = {
    val awaitable: Future[Ok.type] = Future.successful {
      Thread.sleep(waitTime.toMillis)
      OK
    }
    Await.ready(awaitable, waitTime)
  }
```

The remoteService function complaints saying that it is expecting a type. So why this this a problem? Why can't I simply return a Object type?

Comment: you defined the method with return type `ServiceResponse`, but the method body returns `Future[OK.type]` - why would that work? Maybe you meant `Await.result(awaitable, waitTime)` as the last line (which would compile)

Comment: Any reason why you're not returning `Future[ServiceReponse]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you need to use Await.result instead of Await.ready. This works:

```
import scala.concurrent._
import scala.concurrent.duration._

sealed trait ServiceResponse {

  case object OK extends ServiceResponse
  case object SHIT extends ServiceResponse

  private def remoteService(waitTime: FiniteDuration): ServiceResponse = {
    val awaitable: Future[OK.type] = Future.successful {
      Thread.sleep(waitTime.toMillis)
      OK
    }
    Await.result(awaitable, waitTime)
  }

}
```

Also you've got a typo: Future[Ok.Type] should be Future[OK.type]